# Updating one column in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update values in a table that looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| Id | Value       |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | title       |
+----+-------------+
| 2  | description |
+----+-------------+
| 3  | email       |
+----+-------------+
| 4  | keywords    |
+----+-------------+
```

I would like to update the value if the PK already exists, otherwise insert a new row.

submit.php:

```
include('../../include/config.php');

if($_POST['settings']){
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $keywords=$_POST['keywords'];

    $test=$db->query("UPDATE `settings` SET `value` = '$title' WHERE `id` =1, SET `value` = '$description' WHERE `id` =2,SET `value` = '$email' WHERE `id` =3, SET `value` = '$keywords' WHERE `id` =4;");
    if($test){
        echo "good";
    }else{
        echo "bad";
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

To whoever reading this question now, don't use this structure to store your website settings. and I don't recommend using the query either because it is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: How Is Putting A Capitol Letter On Every Word Help Readability!? Its Not Cool And Im Sure It Takes You Longer To Type A Sentence.. And Your More Likely TO Make MiStAkeS In Your CamelCase. Ekkkk

Comment: I guess he wrote all in caps and StackOverflow just camelcased the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query can in fact be done with a single statement in Mysql as long as you have a unique index or primary key on your Id field.

```
INSERT INTO `settings` (`id`,`value`) VALUES (1,?),(2,?),(3,?),(4,?)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=VALUES(`value`);
```

See the documentation of **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY** at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example...

```
SELECT * FROM user;
+---------+------+
| user_id | name |
+---------+------+
|       1 | X    |
|       2 | B    |
|       3 | C    |
+---------+------+

UPDATE user 
   SET name = CASE user_id WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
                           WHEN 2 THEN 'J' 
                           WHEN 3 THEN 'K' END;

SELECT * FROM user;
+---------+------+
| user_id | name |
+---------+------+
|       1 | A    |
|       2 | J    |
|       3 | K    |
+---------+------+
```

Comment: Thank You Bro For Your Help,But This Didn't Work For Me.

Comment: This is my first time seeing this syntax but the documentation on this structure shows END should be END CASE, that may make it functional.

Comment: @RalphRitoch Clearly this works. This is the output from my terminal. The structure is as illustrated.

Comment: @Strawberry, not every version of MySQL supports the same syntax. Regardless I do prefer case syntax over the ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax but I don't know what cross platform issues it may have and the documentation doesn't say what version it became available in.

Comment: @Strawberry, I tested this on my server (v5.6.13) and the END CASE syntax that shows in the MySQL manual for MySQL 5.0 throws an error, but using the syntax you gave it does work. Either the documentation is wrong, or my version of MySQL is wrong.

Comment: It looks like the syntax changes depending on how it's used, END CASE is for compound statements.

Comment: Upvoted this since it is better syntax, even if the syntax changes depending on how it's used.